# neo4j-2-2.5.pom cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: java, maven, gradle, neo4j, gradlew

I know many have asked this sort of thing before but while I've been going over those answers this morning, no dice getting Eclipse to play ball.

The required library in question is neo4j-2.2.5.pom.  It's the only pom file I can see in the referenced libraries, if that's significant.

It's a Gradle project, running gradle version 4.10.  build.gradle follows :-

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.4.6.RELEASE')
    compile("org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator")
    compile('org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:1.5.1')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')    
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('com.github.mxab.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute:2.0.1')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

The actual pom file itself I've dug out of my .gradle directory in my users folder, and you can see that here :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
    <relativePath>../..</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.5</version>

  <name>Neo4j - Community</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <url>http://components.neo4j.org/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}</url>
  <description>A meta package containing the most used Neo4j libraries. Intended use: as a Maven dependency.</description>

  <properties>
    <short-name>neo4j</short-name>
    <version-package>impl.neo4j</version-package>
    <bundle.namespace>org.neo4j</bundle.namespace>
    <license-text.header>GPL-3-header.txt</license-text.header>
    <javadoc.skip>false</javadoc.skip>
    <licensing.prepend.text>notice-gpl-prefix.txt</licensing.prepend.text>
  </properties>

  <scm>
      <url>https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/master/community/neo4j</url>
  </scm>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-lucene-index</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-graph-algo</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-udc</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-graph-matching</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-jmx</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-consistency-check</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For the tests specified by this package -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-io</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-consistency-check</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>GNU General Public License, Version 3</name>
      <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0-standalone.html</url>
      <comments>The software ("Software") developed and owned by Network Engine for
Objects in Lund AB (referred to in this notice as "Neo Technology") is
licensed under the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 3 to all third
parties and that license is included below.

However, if you have executed an End User Software License and Services
Agreement or an OEM Software License and Support Services Agreement, or
another commercial license agreement with Neo Technology or one of its
affiliates (each, a "Commercial Agreement"), the terms of the license in
such Commercial Agreement will supersede the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
Version 3 and you may use the Software solely pursuant to the terms of
the relevant Commercial Agreement.
      </comments>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-filtered-pom</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependency-sources</id>
            <phase>${attach-javadoc-phase}</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/javadoc-sources</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${project.build.directory}/../../cypher/cypher/src/main/java/</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${project.build.directory}/../../graph-algo/src/main/java/</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${project.build.directory}/../../graph-matching/src/main/java/</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${project.build.directory}/../../jmx/src/main/java/</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${project.build.directory}/../../kernel/src/main/java/</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${project.build.directory}/../../kernel/target/generated-sources/</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${project.build.directory}/../../lucene-index/src/main/java/</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadoc</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>create-javadocs</id>
            <phase>${attach-javadoc-phase}</phase>
            <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
              <additionnalDependencies>
                <additionnalDependency>
                  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0.0</version>
                </additionnalDependency>
                <additionnalDependency>
                  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                  <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0.0</version>
                </additionnalDependency>
                <additionnalDependency>
                  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                  <version>1.6.4</version>
                </additionnalDependency>
              </additionnalDependencies>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/apidocs</outputDirectory>
              <sourcepath>${project.build.directory}/javadoc-sources</sourcepath>
              <detectLinks>false</detectLinks>
              <header>${project.name}</header>
              <doctitle>${project.name} ${project.version} API</doctitle>
              <skip>${javadoc.skip}</skip>
              <show>public</show>
              <windowtitle>${project.name} ${project.version} API</windowtitle>
               <excludePackageNames>
                *.impl.*:*.internal.*:org.neo4j.ext.udc:org.neo4j.kernel:org.neo4j.kernel.ha:org.neo4j.kernel.ha.*:org.neo4j.com:org.neo4j.com.*:org.apache.lucene.index:org.neo4j.cluster.*:org.neo4j.helpers.progress:org.neo4j.kernel.configuration:org.neo4j.kernel.guard:org.neo4j.kernel.info:org.neo4j.kernel.logging
               </excludePackageNames>
              <groups>
                <group>
                  <title>Graph database</title>
                  <packages>org.neo4j.graphdb:org.neo4j.graphdb.*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                  <title>Index</title>
                  <packages>org.neo4j.index:org.neo4j.index.*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                  <title>Graph algorithms</title>
                  <packages>org.neo4j.graphalgo:org.neo4j.graphalgo.*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                  <title>Management</title>
                  <packages>org.neo4j.management:org.neo4j.management.*:org.neo4j.jmx:org.neo4j.jmx.*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                  <title>Query language</title>
                  <packages>org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat:org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                  <title>Graph matching</title>
                  <packages>org.neo4j.graphmatching:org.neo4j.graphmatching.*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                  <title>Helpers</title>
                  <packages>org.neo4j.helpers:org.neo4j.helpers.*</packages>
                </group>
                <group>
                  <title>Tooling</title>
                  <packages>org.neo4j.tooling:org.neo4j.tooling.*</packages>
                </group>
              </groups>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I've tried clearing out the .gradle directory and running gradlew again to redownload, no joy.

Comment: Does it work in command line ?

Comment: If you mean using gradlew bootRun at the command line, no it does not, it errors with the same error that I get if I tell Eclipse to run it anyway despite the build problems - "Failed to configure DataSource, url attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured".

I think that's just because the neo4j database stuff is missing so Spring Boot is failing.

Comment: That's a different issue that the one exposed in your question. The original issue is an eclipse's cache one (i guess), this one is about configuration

Comment: Well, i don't think it's caching because I've nuked the cache repeatedly, and even reinstalled a new eclipse.

Though it could well be incorrectly configured, as I've not got it running yet without a build error, and havn't made it to that stage.

Comment: I think I have it. org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa is causes some sort of clash with the org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j dependency.

I still have to manually remove the pom file from the build to get it to work without complaint in Eclipse but i guess maybe that really is the cache.

Thank you ToYonos for your time.  :)